# ServiceStack service not getting autowired in my CustomUserSession

Tags: c#, servicestack

```
 public class SteamUserSession : AuthUserSession
 {
        public UserService UserService { get; set; } //Should be autowired

        public long SteamID { get; private set; }

        public User CurrentUser { get; private set; }

        public Player SteamProfile { get; private set; }

        public List<SteamGame> OwnedApps { get; private set; }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(
            IServiceBase authService,
            IAuthSession session,
            IOAuthTokens tokens,
            Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
            // access servicestack user server and load properies for session here
            CurrentUser = (User)UserService.Get(new GetUser(SteamID));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AuthUserSession` is only a **model** that's persisted and retrieved from a data store, i.e. it's not a service/filter/etc or controller that's resolved (and autowired) from an IOC.

You can instead retrieve dependencies from the IOC with the passed in `authService`, e.g:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(
        IServiceBase authService,
        IAuthSession session,
        IOAuthTokens tokens,
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    // access servicestack user server and load properies for session here
    var userService = authService.TryResolve<UserService>();
    CurrentUser = (User)userService.Get(new GetUser(SteamID));
}
```